# Merging branch in Visual Studio 2015 in TFS not working - target branch doesn't show up

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, merge

I'm seeing a really strange behavior.  When I right click a branch in my solution explorer and select "merge", the merge dialog opens up but there is not target branch field to select where I want to merge.  The Source branch is there, but no target.  I thought maybe it was just the solution that I'm currently working on, but I pulled down an old solution that is doing the same thing.

This is a fresh install of VS 2015 (as of mid-Nov) on a brand new Windows 10 install.  Here's a screenshot of the issue:[image: No target branch]

anyone have any ideas of how I can resolve this?
TIA

Comment: Can you resize the dialog box?

Comment: oh my god!  that was it...so stupid of me.  thanks so much!  Throw that into an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Model Dialog Box has been resized too small to see the rest of the options. This could be a resolution or a DPI thing.

Have you tried resizing the dialog?